# PHP curl Keep-Alive - CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE

Tags: php

regarding CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, the docs says (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
TRUE to force the connection to explicitly close when it
has finished processing, and not be pooled for reuse.
```

If set to FALSE - can I trust the connection to be automatically pooled and reuse, or do I have to do anything specific in the code to support it?, i.e.

1. Do I need to use the same handle? i.e. avoid calling `curl_init()` again and reuse the same value it previously returned?
2. Do I need to avoid calling `curl_close($ch)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you don't have to do anything specific. It's all done "under the hood".
2. You still need to call `curl_init()` and obtain your handle.
3. You should still call `curl_close()`.

In other words, the interface of `curl_*()` methods stays the same. Your code shouldn't change, regarding the use of `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` flag.

`curl_close()` includes, but is not limited to, closing a connection. It's also to free curl and php resources, do clean up.

But really, you should only use `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` flag if you suspect that the server your using doesn't have a properly implemented HTTP continuation.